# How to use Promise in angular2 with firebase to transform login to service

Tags: firebase, promise, angular, ionic2

I'm learning how to code. I'm struggling with promise, and how to use them.

I want to accomplish login using Facebook with Firebase.

The code works perfectly when I don't use this as service

```js
  authWithFacebook(){
    this.usersRef.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }else if (this.isLoggedIn && this.newUser) {
        this.usersRef.child(this.authData.uid).set({
          NomComplet: this.authData.facebook.displayName,
          ProfileCached: this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile,
          Nom : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.last_name,
          Prenom : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.first_name,
          ProfileImg: this.authData.facebook.profileImageURL,
          Agemoyen : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.age_range,
          Localite : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.locale,
        });
      }
    });
    console.log("je suis connecté" + " " + this.authData.facebook.displayName )
  }
```

I attemped to transform my code into a service, which can be used in the entire app. But it doesn't work:

```js
authWithOAuth(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    this.usersRef.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      }else {
        resolve();
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Can anyone can help me with this or tell me which doc to read to fully understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code like this:

```
authWithFacebook(){
  this.authService.authWithOAuth().then(
    () => {
      this.usersRef.child(this.authData.uid).set({
        NomComplet: this.authData.facebook.displayName,
        ProfileCached: this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile,
        Nom : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.last_name,
        Prenom : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.first_name,
        ProfileImg: this.authData.facebook.profileImageURL,
        Agemoyen : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.age_range,
        Localite : this.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.locale,
      });
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

to use the `then` method of promises.